# Remove TR from Table

Tags: javascript, php

I'm drawning a table via PHP echo, containing some data from SQL query. It's a cart script. So when the customer click to remove some item from cart, I want to remove that TR from the table. For this I'll call the javascript function 'removefromcart' passing the item ID and the row index. So this function will remove the item in the cart from SQL, and with the row index delete the TR from table. Here is how I'm trying to do:

```
        <?php
            $uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userlogged']);
            $Query = mysql_query("SELECT id, info FROM cart where username = '$uid'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
            {
                echo '<tr id="OrderTable"> <td> '.htmlspecialchars($row["info"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' </td>';
                $id = $row['id'];
                $NewQuery = mysql_query("SELECT name, date, country, flag, code, med, price FROM products WHERE id = '$id'");
                while($newrow = mysql_fetch_array($NewQuery))
                {
                    echo '<td> '.htmlspecialchars($newrow["name"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' </td>';   
                    echo '<td> '.htmlspecialchars($newrow["date"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' </td>';
                    echo '<td> '.htmlspecialchars($newrow["country"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' </td>';
                    echo '<td> '.htmlspecialchars($newrow["flag"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' </td>';
                    echo '<td> '.htmlspecialchars($newrow["code"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' </td>';
                    echo '<td> '.htmlspecialchars($newrow["med"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' </td>';
                    echo '<td> '.htmlspecialchars($newrow["price"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' </td>';
                    echo '<td><label><a href="javascript:buyfromcart('.htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').')">
                                        <b><img src="/img/buy.png" /></b></a></label>
                                        <label>
                                        <script>
                                            var x = document.getElementById("OrderTable").rowIndex;
        document.write(\'<a href="javascript:removefromcart('.htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').', \'+ x +\')"><b><img src="/img/cancel.png"/></b></a></label> </td> </tr>\') </script>';
                }
            }


         ?>
        </table>
        </div>
```

But the link in the href for the cancel.png image is:

```
javascript:removefromcart(3, 1)
```

Where 3 is the ID for the product (OK), but the second parameter, for every TR in the table, is always 1... Why it's not getting the current row index for the TR?

The HTML output generated is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Shop.su</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function load(url) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = 'Your orders ('+xmlhttp.responseText+')';
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function addtocart(id)
    {
        document.getElementById('add'+id).innerHTML='<b>Added!</b>';
        load('/cart.php?addtocart&dump='+id);
    }

    function removefromcart(id, x)
    {
        alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);   
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="home">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li id="homeicon" class='active'><a href='?news'><span>News</span></a></li>
   <li id="ordersicon"><a href='?orders'><span id="cart">Your Orders (11)</span></a></li>
   <li id="ticketicon" class='last'><a href='?tickets'><span>Tickets</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>    <div id="container">
        <p class="orderpage"> Your current cart items:: </p>
<div class="ResultsTable" >
                <table >
                <tr>
                <td>
                    Type
                </td>
                <td>
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    Country
                </td>
                <td>
                    Flag
                </td>
                <td>
                    Code
                </td>
                <td>
                    Med.
                </td>
                <td>
                    Price
                </td>
                <td>
                    Buy
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="OrderTable"> <td> Mirror </td><td> NewName </td><td> 456789 </td><td> USA </td><td> VISA </td><td> 101 </td><td> 1409 </td><td> 10.00 </td><td><label><a href="javascript:buyfromcart(3)">
                                                <b><img src="/img/buy.png" /></b></a></label>
                                                <label>
                                                <script>
                                                    var x = document.getElementById("OrderTable").rowIndex;
                document.write('<a href="javascript:removefromcart(3, '+ x +')"><b><img src="/img/cancel.png"/></b></a></label> </td> </tr>') </script><tr id="OrderTable"> <td> Track </td><td> New Base123123 </td><td> 456789 </td><td> Brazil </td><td> TEST </td><td> 101 </td><td> 1409 </td><td> 10.00 </td><td><label><a href="javascript:buyfromcart(4)">
                                                <b><img src="/img/buy.png" /></b></a></label>
               </table>
                </div>    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with some more php code? Show us the foreach loop for example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do need the see the full html output and the javascript of your removefromcart method. I can't find the error with only the php code.

Comment: Hi, the answer I accepted previously was not correct, because when I put a variable in PHP couting the rows, if I delete 1 row in the table, all numbers should change, because the table have 1 less, and in PHP it stay the same. So I need a solution in javascript because this way I believe when I remove one row the entire table will get the new number for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
{
   cont++;
   echo '<tr id="myrow' . cont . '">
```

and then:

```
javascript:removefromcart('. $row['id'] .', ' . $cont ')...
```

BTW, I think you should use PDO

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the rendered html it may be more clear what is happening.
You don't need to set `x` with javascript, you can set it in the PHP code by adding a variable that gets incremented in the outside `while` loop.

Comment: I added the html output. The idea about php is very good, I'll try to implement. Thank's.